# How to add year and month path to old attachment images?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, attachments

I was using only uploads folder for attachment images. After a while, I started using also Year and Month folder. But I did realize something today. And that is, new uploads works perfectly but old attachments are not showing, so I mean they are broken.

For example, old path:

```
example.com/img/uploads/file-name.webp
```

New path:

```
example.com/app/uploads/2018/12/file-name.webp
```

After that, I tried to replace or add new path. As far as I know there is no other way. However, it didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
function replace_old_img_path($image_content)
{

    $year = date('Y'); // Year folder
    $month = date('m'); // Month folder

    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $attachment_title = get_the_title($image_id); // Attachment file name

    // Replace old path or add year and month folders after uploads/
    $image_content = str_replace("img/uploads/'.$attachment_title.'.webp", "app/uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$attachment_title.'.webp", $image_content);
    return $image_content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_old_img_path');
```

It didn't work as I said. So how do we solve that? A little help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the post thumbnail URL, use the filter `wp_get_attachment_url`;

Try to follow the next code:

```
// NAV: Change the url for thumbnail for post
function wpcoder_change_post_thumbnail_url($url, $post_id) {
    if (strpos($url, 'img/uploads/') !== false) {
        $year = date('Y'); // Year folder
        $month = date('m'); // Month folder
        $url =  str_replace("img/uploads/", "app/uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/", $url);
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'wpcoder_change_post_thumbnail_url', 10, 2);
```

This filter allows you to modify the URL of an attachment (thumbnail) based on conditions you define. In the example, it checks if the URL contains 'img/uploads/' and replaces it with your custom URL.

You can add the code in the file 'functions.php' or add using the [free plugin WP Coder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-coder/) via page **Global PHP**